# Vue and Node WebSockets - How to authenticate user before establishing connection?

Tags: node.js, http, vue.js, websocket, electron

What would be the best way to provide some checks before client application could successfully establish connection to Node server (for example, Electron application).

**Ipinca** from websocket/ws library suggested to use server.on('upgrade', ...) event listener, but using this, we are only able to check currently sent data from client.

```
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const server = http.createServer();
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, request, ...args) {
  // ...
});

server.on('upgrade', async function upgrade(request, socket, head) {
  // Do what you normally do in `verifyClient()` here and then use
  // `WebSocketServer.prototype.handleUpgrade()`.
  let args;

  try {
    args = await getDataAsync();
  } catch (e) {
    socket.destroy();
    return;
  }

  wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function done(ws) {
    wss.emit('connection', ws, request, ...args);
  });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

But what if we want to check if user is already authenticated and in this case, we don't want to authenticate him again? Would we need to send some http requests before opening WebSocket connection for these checks, and is it a good practice to use same port for Ws and Http protocols?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code helps you to establish a connection if a user is authenticated but make a new connection.
I think in your case you seek to do if the user already authenticated then establish the connection if not then ask him to register.

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously authenticated a user and they are carrying a cookie that identifies them, you can access that data from the `request` argument of your `server.on('upgrade'...` or `wss.on('connection'...` event handlers as an instance of node's [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) class (or something close, anyway).

You can use either the request object itself or the cookie matter from `request.headers.cookie` with your authentication solution, be it middleware or home grown, to verify that the user should be able to continue, the same as you would in an HTTP route.